# Graphical glitches when installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, graphics, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 from a USB onto this old PC. Whenever it gets to the Install Ubuntu / Try Ubuntu screen, a weird graphical glitch starts happening that looks like the image below. This is my first time installing Ubuntu, so I don't know how to resolve this. [Here's what the glitch looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9akUQ.jpg)

Edit: The graphics card is an Nvidia Quadro FX 3500.

Comment: You should perhaps try installing with safe graphics mode. If there's a problem with the installed system then troubleshoot from there. Meanwhile please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications, namely the graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I rebooted in recovery mode and now everything looks fine.